# Where does the Web App take certificate from if I did not add it?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I created a new Web App on D1 App Service Plan. I just published the application (.Net Core 2.2 app) from Visual Studio. I see that I can access my app with HTTPS and the browser tells me that this is a secured connection (with a padlock).
How did that happen? When I go to TLS/SSL section of my Web App settings, there are no certificates added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without the custom domain, you have SSL enabled for your site. By default, Azure secures the *.azurewebsites.net wildcard domain with a single SSL certificate, so your clients can already access your app with https.

Comment: OK, so ALL applications under *.azurewebsites.net  share the same certificate by default. However, if I added my own certificate, I would use this one, right?

Comment: Yes, you can upload your own certificate and configure to use that: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl